# Export xls in birt Single sheet or single tab

Tags: javascript, birt

When I have 1943 page my browser crashes when Page Break Intreval=0.But Browser didn't crash when page interval was 40 .What to do in this case to remove output in single sheet.I have also tried by adding psudo soft emitter jar and try to configure emitter configuration by adding

```
if(format == "xls") {
action = action + " &__emitterid=uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter&__ExcelEmitter.DisplayRowColHeadings=true&__ExcelEmitter.SingleSheet=true";
}
```

in `/WebContent/webcontent/birt/ajax/ui/dialog/BirtExportReportDialog.js`.

However the problem is viewing xls and xlsx and not in Excel if want to change emitter where we need to update the code, please let me know.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

we may need to add some  code in /WebContent/webcontent/birt/ajax/ui/dialog/BirtExportReportDialog.js,make sure that uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters jar is in lib folder .To check the format print some alert messages .so that you can see the message during export.

```
if( format=="xlsx" )
                    {               





                            action = action + "&__emitterid=uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsxEmitter&__ExcelEmitter.DisplayRowColHeadings=true&__ExcelEmitter.SingleSheet=true";

                    }
```